# How can I boot an os on a clean pc?

Tags: linux, operating-system, boot, bios, uefi

I have made bootable an USB key with mint on it. But when I launch my PC HP Pro Book x360 11 GE EE:
it checks the harddisk and sees no boot device with the error hardDisk 3F0 which is normal because the pc is clean.

But when I try to boot it with my USB key I don't find it there is just the ipv4 and ipv6 boot option.

- [BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O406s.jpg)
- [Boot option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mHXU.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). This question might be more on topic at another site in the stack exchange collection of Q&A sites, perhaps superuser.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a problem in the way the bootable USB drive has been created. Judging from the images that you have provided, your PC is booting only in secure (UEFI) mode and maybe the problems could be:

- The drive has been created in "classic" bios mode (very strange since Ubuntu supports UEFI).
- The USB drive has not been created correctly
- I'm not really an expert in HP laptops but maybe there is an option to disable booting from usb drives (every model is always a little bit different from others). Perhaps you could find more on the manifacturer's website or in the manual.

For first and second cases try to see if there is a way to disable secure boot (just to try if the usb drive is bootable but it is not recommended) and maybe try to recreate the USB drive in UEFI mode (there are plenty of posts on Ubuntu and Linux forums on how to do it). If it still doesn't work maybe it's the third case so try to see if booting from USB drive has been disabled.

Comment: It was a problem of booting my usb key, it was not detected as a os starter. Same during the start of my os installed on the hardisk. But it worked finaly.